# .stop() behaving oddly in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress portfolio site. I mocked up the navigation in a codepen and it's working the way I would like it to. http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/GgjgVE

```
    $(".menu-item").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").stop().slideDown(500);
 });  
    $(".menu-item").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").stop().slideUp(500);
    });
```

However, when I update my project files in Wordpress, the drop-down sub-menu is not visible. When I remove .stop() from the jQuery function, the drop-down sub-menu is visible on mouseover, but the animation loops endlessly. http://www.elainematthias.com/

I also had the drop-down sub-menu working with the code below, but I'd prefer to soften the sub-menu appearance with .slideDown() and .slideUp() or a comparable animated effect.

```
$(".menu-item").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find("ul").css("display","block")
        })
        $(".menu-item").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("ul").css("display","none")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `height: 1px;` from sub-menu `<ul>`.

less code for jQuery function

```
$(".menu-item").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").stop().slideDown(500);
 },function(){
        $(this).find("ul").stop().slideUp(500);
    });
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/L05h18ue/4/